# how to put many to many relation query result to grid view in yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

i am working on a content-tag system using yii2.

I have a Content(PK:id) table, I have a Tag(PK:id) table, and I have a junction table called Content_Tag (PK:content_id, tag_id).

now i want to show all content with same keywords in a grid view (sortable, searchable just as content index page) on keyword view page.

i'm using `via` in keywords Class according to the documentation as following:

```
 /**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getContent() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Content_Tag::className(), ['content_id' => 'id']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getContents()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Tag::className(), ['tag_id' => 'tag_id'])->viaTable('content_tag', ['content_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Although I can get contents using `keyword->contents`, but i think it returned as array not `ActiveQuery` as  `content::find()` is.

I create a new KeywordContentSearch Model base on ContentSearch Model:

```
//$query = Content::find();
$query = Keyword::findOne($params['keyword_id'])->contents;
```

and modify the controller in action view

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $searchModel = new KeywordContentSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search([Yii::$app->request->queryParams, 'keyword_id'=>$id]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Now the error log shows `$query` in search model in non-object.

How to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

using keyword->getContents() instead of keyword->contents. done

Comment: I have the same problem. What do you mean using hasmany()? Can you add more thorough answer?

Comment: I used `$query = Countries::findOne($params['country'])->hasMany();`. But it gives error Missing argument 1 for yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::hasMany().